# How to extract a table with DocX?

Tags: c#, docx

I'm extracting text out of an MS Word document (.docx). I'm using the DocX C# library for this purpose, which works in general quit well. No, I want to be able to extract tables. The main problem is, that if I'm looping through the paragraphs, I can get whether I'm in a table cell with:

```
        ParentContainer == Cell
```

but I do not get any information about how many rows and cells. Second possibility which I see is that there is a list with tables as property of the document object. There I can see, how many rows / columns and so on - but I do not know where they are.

Does anyone has an idea how to deal with tables correctly? Any other solution would be appreciated as well :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The trick is, to check whether each paragraph is followed by a table. This can be done by

```
...
if (paragraph.FollowingTable != null)
{
    tableId = paragraph.FollowingTable.Index;
} 
...
```

The `FollowingTable.Index` will give you an index to the table, with which you can get all details about the table in the `Document.Tables` list.